# Getting Values to Dropdown from Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to pull a list from my ViewModel to populate a drop-down.  I can get the objects from the Model and pass them to the View, but the view just shows the name of the ViewModel as the value in the dropdown.  Not sure how to get the actual values to the Dropdown or if am going in the wrong direction.  No intellesence past the definition of the object "model.InitialFeesChart".  Thanks in advance for looking.

Controller:  Objects contain needed data

```
   public ActionResult CreateFranchise()
    {
        var model = new FranchiseVM();
        model.FranStates = new List<string> { "AZ", "NV", "CA" };

        //Grap the Package Identificaton to determine Package selected by Franshise
        model.InitialFeesChart = (from f in _db.InitalFeesCharts
                            select new InitalFeesChartVM {IFCPackage = f.IFCPackage}).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace Compass.Models
{
    public class FranchiseVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int FranchiseID { get; set; }
        public string FranPID { get; set; }
        public string FranBusinessName { get; set; }
        public string FranAddress { get; set; }
        public string FranCity { get; set; }
        public string FranState { get; set; }
        public string FranPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string FranPhonePrimary { get; set; }
        public string FranPhonePrimaryCell { get; set; }
        public string FranFAX { get; set; }
        public string FranOwnerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string FranOwnerLastName { get; set; }
        public string FranAlternateFirstName { get; set; }
        public string FranAlternateLastName { get; set; }
        public string FranAlternatePhone { get; set; }
        public string FranNotes { get; set; }
        public string IFCPackageCurrent { get; set; }

        public IList<string> FranStates { get; set; }

        //public IList<InitalFeesChartVM> InitialFeesChart { get; set; }
```

//Added

```
public string IFCPackage { get; set; }

            private readonly List<InitialFeesChart> _InitialFeesChart;
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IFCItems
            {
                get { return new SelectList(_InitialFeesChart, "InitialFeesID", "IFCPackage"); }

            }



    }
}
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IFCPackageCurrent, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IFCPackageCurrent, Model.IFCItems))
        </div>
    </div>
```

Final working code:

ViewModel

```
    public IList<InitalFeesChartVM> InitialFeesChart { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Franchise Package")]
    public string IFCPackageCurrent { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IFCPackageCurrent, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IFCPackageCurrent, new SelectList(Model.InitialFeesChart, "InitialFeesID", "IFCPackage"))
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateFranchise()
        {
            var model = new FranchiseVM();
            model.FranStates = new List<string> { "AZ", "NV", "CA" };

            model.InitialFeesChart = (from f in _db.InitalFeesCharts select new InitalFeesChartVM { IFCPackage = f.IFCPackage, InitialFeesID = f.InitialFeesID }).ToList();


            return View(model);
```

Comment: You are using the helper in a wrong way. See this article how to do it right - http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Thanks, added the code in.  The values are null though.  See my edits.  Not sure how to initialize the List?

Comment: I guess there is a comment in the notes that says "Assuming you populate the _flavors..."  not sure now how to populate the data..

Comment: First - `Juventus18` answer is pretty good (I opened the link and checked it) so the easiest way for you would be to use it directly with slight changes as he explains in his answer.

Comment: In your case `flavors` is `model.InitialFeesChart = (from f in _db.InitalFeesCharts
                            select new InitalFeesChartVM {IFCPackage = f.IFCPackage}).ToList();`

Comment: So in your action `CreateFranchise()` you would want something like : `model.InitialFeesChart = (from f in _db.InitalFeesCharts
                            select new InitalFeesChartVM {InitialFeesID = f.InitialFeesID, IFCPackage = f.IFCPackage }).ToList();` which means you should have those two properties in your `InitalFeesChartVM` class.

Comment: Ok, here is your code, thanks to the efforts of `Juventus18` - http://dotnetfiddle.net/rwK7ew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify what properties to use in the Select List. Specify the value field and the text field like this: `SelectList(Items, "Id", "Title")`

I've created a fiddle that uses your classes. You will have to change the string values in the part when the select list is created so that they match the properties you want to use from your `InitalFeesChartVM`   http://dotnetfiddle.net/9052ZH

Comment: I think this would be good if I where adding in static data into the dropdown?  but I am actually trying to pull from a model with exsisting data already there.  I get the objects to populate with the data I am looking for, just cannot get it to the dropdown.  Trying a few variations of your code.